# conditional mysql query multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables in mysql database as shown below.  I am looking for a query that will select * from books but if preview_image = 'none' then preview_image = the hash_id of the row with the largest size where books.id = images.parentid.  Hope this makes sense.

```
table books
+----------------+---------------+
| id    | title  | preview_image |
+----------------+---------------+
| 1     | book1  | 55859076d906  |
| 2     | book2  | 20a14f9fd7cf  |
| 3     | book3  | none          |
| 4     | book4  | ce805ecff5c9  |
| 5     | book5  | e60a7217b3e2  |
+----------------+---------------+

table images
+-------------+------+---------------+
| parentid    | size | hash_id       |
+--------------------+---------------+
| 2           | 100  | 55859076d906  |
| 1           | 200  | 20a14f9fd7cf  |
| 3           | 300  | 34805fr5c9e5  |
| 3           | 400  | ce805ecff5c9  |
| 3           | 500  | e60a7217b3e2  |
+--------------------+---------------+
```

Thanks

Comment: It could make sense if you showed what you tried.

Comment: I haven't really tried anything yet.  I am not familiar with conditional queries.  I believe I would also need a subselect.  Maybe something like:  select * from books if(books.preview_image = 'none' , select hash_id from images where images.parentid =books.id order by size desc limit 0,1))  something like this.  I am not sure tho.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to obtain the first record from a sorted [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat), and switch using a [`CASE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) expression:

```
SELECT   books.id, books.title, CASE books.preview_image
           WHEN 'none' THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(
             GROUP_CONCAT(images.hash_id ORDER BY images.size DESC SEPARATOR ',')
           , ',', 1)
           ELSE books.preview_image
         END AS preview_image
FROM     books LEFT JOIN images ON images.parentid = books.id
GROUP BY books.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a subquery that finds the desired hash ID for each parent ID, using one of the techniques in [SQL Select only rows with Max Value on a Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column?rq=1). Then join this with the `books` table.

```
SELECT b.id, b.title, IF(b.preview_image = 'none', i.hash_id, b.preview_image) AS image
FROM books AS b
LEFT JOIN (SELECT i1.parentid, i1.hash_id
           FROM images AS i1
           JOIN (SELECT parentid, MAX(size) AS maxsize
                 FROM images
                 GROUP BY parentid) AS i2
           ON i1.parentid = i2.parentid AND i1.size = i2.size) AS i
ON b.id = i.parentid
```